# Any necessary and sufficient condition for $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking for any established result that is necessary and sufficient for $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$ for any real sequences $\{a_n\} \text{and} \{b_n\}\ne 0$, where both the two sequences converges to the same limit.

---

Can any one help me with some hints comments or suggestions?

Comment: If the limit of the two sequences is nonzero, what happens to the ratios of the terms $a_n/b_n$?

Comment: @RobinSaunders I need a necessary and sufficient condition that will force the ratio $a_n/b_n$ to converge to $0$.

Comment: Yes. I'm giving you a hint.

Comment: your `both sequences converges to the same limit` confused me !

Comment: @chouaib Suppose $a_n=|x_{n+1}-x|$ and $b_n=|x_n-x|$

Comment: @RobinSaunders If that is the case, then I do not understand your hint.

Comment: See if you can answer the question I asked, and it will move you toward solving your problem.

Comment: @RobinSaunders $a_n/b_n\to 1$, since both the sequences converge to the same limit.

Comment: Right, so we've ruled out the possibility of the limit of the sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ being nonzero. Have you read Pierre's answer below?

Comment: @RobinSaunders Yes but I am thinking for the cases he mention at the last line of his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Necessary/sufficient conditions type of problems can sometimes seem hard to start, but there are techniques to easily approach them.

One way is to start with a necessary condition (respectively, a sufficient condition), and *improve* on it until you feel your necessary condition becomes sufficient (respectively, until your sufficient condition becomes also necessary), and then try to prove that it is in fact sufficient (resp. necessary).

For example,
as Robin Saunders commented,
if $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ with $a,b$ nonzero and not $\pm\infty$,
then the quotient rule for limits (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties)) implies that the radio $a_n/b_n$ will converge to $a/b\neq0$.
Thus,
a first necessary condition is the following:

> At least one of $a_n$ or $b_n$ converges to $0$ or $\pm\infty$.

Is this condition also sufficient? Clearly not,
as $a_n=n^2$ and $b_n=n$ are both such that $a_n,b_n\to\infty$,
so the necessary condition is satisfied,
yet $a_n/b_n$ converges to + infinity!

So the work is not done: you have to make your necessary condition *stronger*, i.e., dismiss other cases that won't work. However, you're not as far as you were when you started, because now you only have to consider the cases where at least one of $a_n$ or $b_n$ converges to $0$ or $\pm\infty$.